# How pass data from parent fragment to child kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, listener, bundle

I have parent fragment,in which i do http request,but wordpress api return only one page,so i have child fragment,which have buttons,to move page back and forward. In parent fragment i load child fragment,and it ask parent fragment to load url.

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        var view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_itemnews_list, container, false)
        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.pagecontainer,fragment,"page").commit()
//initialization of views
        childFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener("", this,{ key,b ->
            run(url,b)
        })
return view
    }
```

## Expected results

I expect,what my parent fragment add page fragment and page fragment will ask parent fragment load url for first page. But this not happen.

In run(url) function i do http request and in the main thread set result for child fragment,to notify it,what data was loaded successfully and we can move page.

```
private fun run(url: String,b:Bundle) {
//do http request via okhttpclient,and if all ok,do:
activity!!.runOnUiThread {
//do something with ui elements,and notify child fragment,what all ok.
                                childFragmentManager.setFragmentResult("", b)
}
}
```

In my child fragment PageFragment i send request to parent fragment,to do http request.

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view:View =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false)
...
//to move on previous or on next page
        mPrev.setOnClickListener {
pressPrevOrNextButton(-1)
        }
        mNext.setOnClickListener {
pressPrevOrNextButton(1)
        }
        parentFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener("a",this, { _,b ->
movePage(b.getInt("direction",0))
        }
return view
}
```

movePage method only apply results,if data was loaded successful via parent fragment. Now you will see function,which send request to the parent fragment,to it do http request for specific page.

```
fun pressPrevOrNextButton(direction: Int) {
    mPrev.isVisible=false
    mNext.isVisible=false
parentFragmentManager.setFragmentResult("a",bundleOf(Pair("page",page), Pair("per_page",per_page),Pair("direction",direction)))
}
```

Now you will see the code,how i call parent fragment in activity.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        val name =intent.getStringExtra("name")
                if(name!=null &&name.length>0) supportActionBar?.title = getString(if(intent.getStringExtra("type").equals("tag")) R.string.title_tags else R.string.title_all) + ": " + name
//adding the parent fragment
        fragment= FragmentNews(intent.getStringExtra("url")!!,"desc","date",intent.getBooleanExtra("search",false))
       supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mycontainer,fragment,"posts").commit()
    }
```

In gradle i have:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.12'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.4.21"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-rc01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Before i have all this logic,including moving between pages in one activity,and all works ok,but i want to implement moving of pages in several places,so to avoid repeating almost the same code in several places,i decided move it in separate fragment. Help me fix the issue,why my parent fragment not get event from listener? Whether it issue of FragmentResult api,which i should immediately report to google? If yes,how i can do it,i.e what link should i use,to report this issue? Thanks everybody very much for any help.

Comment: Start using `safe args` from Navigation component: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8I8Xykqn4hk

Answer (score 0):

It is so difficult to understand your question. But I still try to answer, hope that it will help you.
You can use Navigation Component and pass data from child fragment to parent fragment:
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#start

Another solution, check this document for see the way pass data between child and parent fragments.
https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#pass-parent-child

Comment: But in secondin your link on fragment result api it's probably some typo in example code,because when i try to do parentFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener("a") { _,b ->
            movePage(b.getInt("direction",0))
        },i get compilation error: No value passed for parameter 'p1'. Or it's issue of the latest kotlin,which i should immediately report to google.

Comment: Ok,i will try explain my problem again. I have parent and child fragment. Child fragment send data to parent fragment. After successful results parent fragment send data to child fragment,to notify,what parent fragment can do some work. I noteced,what when i send data to parent fragment,parent fragment not receive it,but in child fragment listener works. Why parent fragment not receive data,i not understand. I did an example,which demonstrate this issue. You can see it on https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xjdt-RD2CRMu3WUmnazp0osUPNjJrBIx/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: I reported issue to google,which show this problem at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177734529.